# Is there anything behind this door in Venice?

Tags: metro-last-light

In `Metro: Last Light`, Venice, there is a child who lost his teddy bear. I was able to find his bear and return it, but then ended up leaving the city before I could return to see if he and his mother finally moved out of the way of the door.

Because `Metro: Last Light` does not allow you to save games wherever you like, it would be difficult to get back to that moment in time in the game.

Does anyone know if that door may open? And if so, is there anything worthwhile behind it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing behind the door (or rather, you can't access it). Giving the child the teddy bear just helps you to get the good ending and you get the "reunion" achievement.

Comment: Hmm. But the door was pulsing to indicate I could interact with it, so strange. Thanks. Will select as correct when enough time has passed.

Comment: The most you can do, is knock against it. There are many doors, some can be interacted with, but you only knock against them.

Comment: So when the old dude said "Get some sleep" there was actually nowhere to sleep I guess

Comment: Pretty much - just a little market, the shooting gallery and the brothel (to continue the main quest).